# Is there a video player that can do auto refresh rate switching?

Tags: video, video-player, playback, quality, framerate

If the refresh rate of video mode matches frame rate of video stream/file, playback is as smooth as possible. In case of interlaced video, double refresh rate is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [mpv-plugin-xrandr](https://gitlab.com/lvml/mpv-plugin-xrandr) script available for `mpv`.

As for interlaced content, see [this issue](https://gitlab.com/lvml/mpv-plugin-xrandr/issues/1).